# How to make a line chart in Javascript from CSV?

Tags: javascript

I am a python developer, but there is a small part that I need to complete in Javascript, I am unable to figure it out.

This needs to be done in a local computer only. I have a `.csv` file with two columns, and I Need to make a real-time line chart (it reads csv file every X seconds and refresh).

I tried some code from online, they work only with real url. My file is local, so I get this error in all the code I tried by copy/pasting.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Programs/Stock/test.csv' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

It would be great, If someone can help me with this, otherwise I need to learn Javascript from scratch.

CSV: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/632d4bc742d39f5fe8e820f62aa2e47d20210615070639/32404d

Comment: Hi Rahul, send the CSV, I'll post whole project here with proper code

Comment: I think for you it will better to use a library like d3js that will solve the data loading and the graph part, have a look: https://d3-wiki.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/master/CSV/

Comment: I tried it, but I am getting the same error (cross origin requests etc) @MarioSantini

Comment: Sorry, it cannot be possible to access local files without disabling security on modern browsers. d3js can help you on the task, but you have to set a minimal http server that works just local to serve your page and your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic example of plotting data from the python flask and HTML + JS.

Python Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def start():
    data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    x = data['time']
    y = data['value2']
    return render_template("a.html",x=list(x), y=list(y))

app.run()
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="myDiv">

    </div>
    <script>
        var trace1 = {
            x: {{x|safe}},
            y: {{y|safe}},
            type: 'scatter'
        };

        var data = [trace1];

        Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the very basic example, you can use flask-socketio for making it live and then you can emit data based on suitable conditions. Let me know if you need any assistance over that.